# Is it possible to get a search term parameter into getServerSideProps()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm creating a page where I can get an overview of all my notes/summaries.

The note's pages are markdown files converted into HTML used in a dynamic file (this works).

On the notes pages (with all the notes listed), I want to implement a search function:
I need to find a way to get the value of my search input into the `getServerSideProps()`. This way it can filter out the notes and only display the ones that you searched for.

**Things to note:**

- When I change the string 'searchTerm' in `getServerSideProps()` in the note page the search function works.

```js
const searchTerm = "" ;
```

- I can't move the `getAllNotes()` outside the `getServerSideProps()`, because the imports of the data file can't be accessed on the client-side.

```js
const allNotes = getAllNotes();
```

- The searchbar needs to be centered, I know.

Code for the note page:

```js
import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Footer from '../../components/Footer.js';
import Navigation from '../../components/Navigation';

import { Rating } from '@material-ui/core';
import Chip from '../../components/Chip.js';

import noteStyle from '../../styles/Notes.module.css';
import styles from '../../styles/Home.module.css';


import { getAllNotes } from '../../lib/data';
import Search from '../../components/Search';
export default function Notes({ notes }) {
  return (
    <div id="top" className={styles.container}>
      <Head></Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <section>
          <Navigation />
        </section>
        <section className={noteStyle.noteSection}>
          <h1>Notes & Summaries</h1>
          
          <Search />

          <div className={noteStyle.notes}>
            {notes.map((note) => (
              <Link key={note.slug} href={`/note/${note.slug}`}>
                <a key={note.slug} className={noteStyle.noteCard}>
                  <h2 key="title">{note.title}</h2>
                  <h3 key="author">{note.author}</h3>
                  <p key="abstract">
                    {note.abstract}
                  </p>
                  <div className={noteStyle.aboutNote}>
                    <Rating key="rating" className={noteStyle.rating} name="half-rating-read" defaultValue={note.rating} precision={0.5} readOnly />
                    <Chip key="label" className={noteStyle.noteChip} bgColor={note.labelColors[0]} text={note.labelText[0]} icon={note.labelIcons[0]} />
                  </div>
                </a>
              </Link>
            ))}

          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const allNotes = getAllNotes();
  const searchTerm = "";

  //Searches in title, author & abstract data field for a match with the query
  const searchNotes = allNotes.filter((note) => {
    return note.data.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || note.data.author.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || note.data.abstract.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  });

  

  return {
    props: {
      //Here data serialising (dates, urls, ...),
      notes: searchNotes.map(({ data, content, slug }) => ({
        ...data,
        content,
        slug,
      })),

    },
  };
};
```

Code for the search component:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Search() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const search = (e) => {
        setInput(e.target.value);
        console.log("You searched", input);
    }

    return (
        <div className={style.search}>
                <SearchIcon className={style.search__inputIcon}/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a note..." value={input} onChange={search} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Code for the `getAllNotes` (this function converts all the markdown files into HTML):

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import matter from 'gray-matter';

const contentDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), '_content');

export function getAllNotes() {
  const allNotes = fs.readdirSync(contentDirectory);

  return allNotes.map(fileName => {
    const slug = fileName.replace('.md', '');
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(
      path.join(contentDirectory, fileName),
      'utf-8'
    )
    const {content, data} = matter(fileContents);
    return {
      data,
      content,
      slug,
    };  
  })
}
```

Research I used while building the page:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQIv-biWxjo&t=1291s&ab_channel=HarryWolff
- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching
- https://medium.com/@matswainson/building-a-search-component-for-your-next-js-markdown-blog-9e75e0e7d210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a value from the client-side code available to `getServerSideProps` you can pass a query param on the URL with a [`router.push`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush).

```js
// In your `Notes` or `Search` component

router.push('/notes?searchTerm=hello');
```

You can then access the value from the query param in `getServerSideProps`.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const searchTerm = context.query.searchTerm ?? "" // `context.query.searchTerm` would contain "hello"

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried this example and it works. But only on my localhost. When I try to host this one it gives a 500: Internal Sever Error.  Here is the [URL](https://portfolio-wilmox.vercel.app/notes).  
In the console you can also see that it gives a 500 for the GET /notes ...
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue when running the production build locally (`next build && next start`)? Also, can you show your current `getServerSideProps` code? It's most likely related to something in there (maybe in `getAllNotes` code).

Comment: I tried to locally build & start and it works as expected. I opened a new question regarding this new issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153821/vercel-causes-500-internal-server-error-works-on-localhost). All the relevant code should be there. :)