# Vercel causes 500: Internal Server Error (works on localhost)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm creating a page where I can get an overview of all my notes/summaries.

The note's pages are markdown files converted into HTML used in a dynamic file.
The '/note' page is 1 page with a group of all the notes. Now I want to implement a search function to sort the notes.

When I run `npm run dev` it starts the localhost and everything works fine (also the search bar).
But when I push to my Github repo & when it deploys on Vercel, it gives a 500: Internal Server Error.

In the Vercel log you can see that the /note is a server-side page because it has the "λ" symbol.

> 18:40:46.860  λ /notes    12.2 kB     104 kB

Is it the `router.push("/notes")` that is causing this or something else?

Source code: https://github.com/Wilmox/portfolio
Vercel hosted page: https://portfolio-p3hy5j90k-wilmox.vercel.app/

Here is also a gif of the problem in action: [image: 500: Internal Server Error]

I hope someone can help me :)

Code for my notes/index.js:

```js
import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';
import styles from '../../styles/Home.module.css';
import Footer from '../../components/Footer.js';
import Navigation from '../../components/Navigation';
import { Rating } from '@material-ui/core';
import Chip from '../../components/Chip.js';

import noteStyle from '../../styles/Notes.module.css';

import { getAllNotes } from '../../lib/data';
import Search from '../../components/Search';

export default function Notes({ notes }) {
  return (
    <div id="top" className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <section>
          <Navigation />
        </section>
        <section className={noteStyle.noteSection}>
          <header>
            <h1>Notes & Summaries</h1>
            <p>These are notes I&apos;ve taken or summaries I&apos;ve made of the things I read or listen to. Parts may come straight from the source, while others are written by me. <br />
            I do this to get the author&apos;s high-level idea or to brush up on something for later, or for people who don&apos;t feel like reading / listening to a whole book.</p>
          </header>
          
          <Search />

          <div className={noteStyle.notes}>
            {notes.map((note) => (
              <Link key={note.slug} href={`/note/${note.slug}`}>
                <a key={note.slug} className={noteStyle.noteCard}>
                  <h2 key="title">{note.title}</h2>
                  <h3 key="author">{note.author}</h3>
                  <p key="abstract">
                    {note.abstract}
                  </p>
                  <div className={noteStyle.aboutNote}>
                    <Rating key="rating" className={noteStyle.rating} name="half-rating-read" defaultValue={note.rating} precision={0.5} readOnly />
                    <Chip key="label" className={noteStyle.noteChip} bgColor={note.labelColors[0]} text={note.labelText[0]} icon={note.labelIcons[0]} />
                  </div>
                </a>
              </Link>
            ))}

          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const allNotes = getAllNotes();

  const searchTerm = context.query.search ?? "";

  let searchNotes = allNotes;

  if (searchTerm != null) {
    searchNotes =  searchNotes.filter((note) => {
      //Searches in title, author & abstract data field for a match with the query
      return note.data.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || note.data.author.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || note.data.abstract.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    });
  }

  
  
  return {
    props: {
      //Here data serialising (dates, urls, ...),
      notes: searchNotes.map(({ data, content, slug }) => ({
        ...data,
        content,
        slug,
      })),

    },
  };
};
```

Code for the Search.js component

```js
import style from './Search.module.css';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Search() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (input != '') {
            router.push('/notes?search=' + input);
            console.log("You searched for ", input);
        } else {
            router.push('/notes');
        }
      }, [input]);

    const search = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setInput(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div className={style.search}>
                <SearchIcon className={style.search__inputIcon}/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a note..." value={input} onChange={search} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Vercel build log:

```
18:40:23.357    Cloning github.com/Wilmox/portfolio (Branch: main, Commit: afef201)
18:40:23.965    Cloning completed: 607.51ms
18:40:23.981    Analyzing source code...
18:40:25.095    Installing build runtime...
18:40:26.928    Build runtime installed: 1.833s
18:40:29.439    Looking up build cache...
18:40:29.580    Build cache found. Downloading...
18:40:32.275    Build cache downloaded [37.34 MB]: 2694.570ms
18:40:33.436    Installing dependencies...
18:40:33.440    Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7...
18:40:34.913    up to date in 1s
18:40:34.913    156 packages are looking for funding
18:40:34.913      run `npm fund` for details
18:40:34.922    Detected Next.js version: 11.1.0
18:40:34.927    Running "npm run build"
18:40:35.193    > portfolio@1.0.0 build
18:40:35.193    > next build
18:40:35.905    info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
18:40:36.056    info  - Checking validity of types...
18:40:37.907    ./pages/index.js
18:40:37.907    28:9  Warning: Custom fonts not added at the document level will only load for a single page. This is discouraged. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-page-custom-font.  @next/next/no-page-custom-font
18:40:37.908    72:15  Warning: Image elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
18:40:37.908    85:15  Warning: Image elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
18:40:37.908    ./pages/note/[slug].js
18:40:37.908    26:9  Warning: Custom fonts not added at the document level will only load for a single page. This is discouraged. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-page-custom-font.  @next/next/no-page-custom-font
18:40:37.908    ./pages/notes/index.js
18:40:37.909    24:9  Warning: Custom fonts not added at the document level will only load for a single page. This is discouraged. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-page-custom-font.  @next/next/no-page-custom-font
18:40:37.909    ./pages/projects/index.js
18:40:37.909    19:9  Warning: Custom fonts not added at the document level will only load for a single page. This is discouraged. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-page-custom-font.  @next/next/no-page-custom-font
18:40:37.910    32:15  Warning: Image elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
18:40:37.910    45:15  Warning: Image elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
18:40:37.910    58:15  Warning: Image elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
18:40:37.910    71:15  Warning: Image elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
18:40:37.910    ./components/Search.js
18:40:37.910    17:10  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'router'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
18:40:37.911    info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
18:40:37.911    info  - Creating an optimized production build...
18:40:44.074    info  - Compiled successfully
18:40:44.076    info  - Collecting page data...
18:40:45.109    info  - Generating static pages (0/8)
18:40:45.558    info  - Generating static pages (2/8)
18:40:46.768    info  - Generating static pages (4/8)
18:40:46.784    info  - Generating static pages (6/8)
18:40:46.830    info  - Generating static pages (8/8)
18:40:46.832    info  - Finalizing page optimization...
18:40:46.859    Page                                                           Size     First Load JS
18:40:46.859    ┌ ○ /                                                          3.62 kB        99.1 kB
18:40:46.859    ├   └ css/72e3b52ac8c0e0986525.css                             2.5 kB
18:40:46.859    ├   /_app                                                      0 B            67.4 kB
18:40:46.859    ├ ○ /404                                                       194 B          67.6 kB
18:40:46.859    ├ λ /api/hello                                                 0 B            67.4 kB
18:40:46.860    ├ ● /note/[slug] (3945 ms)                                     2.97 kB        95.1 kB
18:40:46.860    ├   └ css/0825cd3181548be7acd8.css                             2.6 kB
18:40:46.860    ├   ├ /note/a-brief-history-of-time (1423 ms)
18:40:46.860    ├   ├ /note/rich-dad-poor-dad (1232 ms)
18:40:46.860    ├   ├ /note/how-to-win-friends-and-influence-people (1044 ms)
18:40:46.860    ├   └ /note/the-magic-of-thinking-big
18:40:46.860    ├ λ /notes                                                     12.2 kB         104 kB
18:40:46.860    ├   └ css/48d66f471e6a5bb11874.css                             2.13 kB
18:40:46.860    └ ○ /projects                                                  1.35 kB        93.7 kB
18:40:46.860        └ css/bf38675255d10289bb03.css                             1.39 kB
18:40:46.860    + First Load JS shared by all                                  67.4 kB
18:40:46.860      ├ chunks/framework.2191d1.js                                 42.4 kB
18:40:46.860      ├ chunks/main.9399b7.js                                      23.6 kB
18:40:46.860      ├ chunks/pages/_app.4003d7.js                                586 B
18:40:46.860      ├ chunks/webpack.ddd010.js                                   822 B
18:40:46.860      └ css/9b9279095ab98c9a275c.css                               752 B
18:40:46.862    λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
18:40:46.862    ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
18:40:46.862    ●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
18:40:46.862       (ISR)     incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)
18:40:46.862    Next.js Analytics is enabled for this production build. You'll receive a Real Experience Score computed by all of your visitors.
18:40:48.949    Traced Next.js server files in: 1.983s
18:40:59.634    Created all serverless functions in: 10.686s
18:41:00.140    Uploading build outputs...
18:41:01.138    Deploying build outputs...
18:41:06.098    Build completed. Populating build cache...
18:41:29.887    Uploading build cache [37.28 MB]...
18:41:30.595    Build cache uploaded: 708.32ms
18:41:31.120    Done with "package.json"
```

Comment: what is the difference between `note` folder and `notes` folder?

Comment: @hisam the `notes` folder is for the page with all my notes displayed and when you click a note you go to the slug of that note (inside the `note` folder).

Comment: Mine works locally and gives me a 500 on Vercel as well. I have deduced that my issue is coming from a 413 payload size response which gets converted into a 500. If you go to your vercel app dashboard, you can click on "Functions" and see the error logs.

Comment: I second Joshu's suggestion of using Vercel's "Functions" menu to view your error logs. In my case, this was being caused by that particular page having a large amount of page data (> 8MB). The solution was trimming down the payload I was returning in my getStaticProps

Comment: I see that some people here have been able to figure out the cause from the "Functions" logs, but in my case, I am not even getting anything on the logs. The page says 500 and Vercel behaves as if nothing ever happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 1 year and 9 months, I managed to fix this issue.
Apparently, it was a known **vulnerability** in NextJS 11. The complete description of the vulnerability can be found at [CVE-2021-43803](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-43803)

So to fix this issue you simply need to upgrade to `NextJS 12.1.0` or above.

I appreciate everyone's assistance in trying to come up with a solution.