# How To apply filters and pagination in getserversideprops in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, next.js, pagination

I am trying to apply filter and pagination on my product list page. but I don't know how to pass values to getServersideprops same as when we fetch data in useEffect and pass the updated values as dependency in react js

Here is my Code
Thanks in advance

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {

  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/products?page=1&limit=20&sortBy=price&sortAs=asc`);
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {productsData: data}
  }
}


function Home({ productsData}) {

  const products =  productsData?.data.products &&  productsData.data.products?.map((item) => {
    return item
  })
  

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Latest Products</h1>
        <Row>
          {products.map((product) => (
            <Col key={product.id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
              <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
                <Link href={`/product/${product.id}`}>
                  <Card.Img src={product.image} variant="top" />
                </Link>

                <Card.Body>
                  <Link href={`/product/${product.id}`}>
                    <Card.Title as="div">
                      <strong>{product.name}</strong>
                    </Card.Title>
                  </Link>

                  <Card.Text as="div">
                    <Rating
                      value={product.rating}
                      text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
                    />
                  </Card.Text>

                  <Card.Text as="h3">${product.price}</Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
    </>
  );

}


export default Home
```

Comment: To pass values from the client-side to `getServerSideProps` you can use query parameters, which will be available under the `context` object passed to `getServerSideProps`. See [Is it possible to get a search term parameter into getServerSideProps()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69150064/is-it-possible-to-get-a-search-term-parameter-into-getserversideprops).

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL parameters and get it in getServerSideProps

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
const limit = query.limit;
const page = query.page;
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/products?page=${page}&limit=${limit}&sortBy=price&sortAs=asc`);
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {productsData: data,page,limit}
  }
}
```